# Multiple protocol filtering on Wireshark

Tags: filtering, wireshark

I would like to filter packages containing either HTTP, IRC, or DNS messages.

Can you recommend any command to do this with Wireshark?

Answer (score 8):

How about this?

```
http or irc or dns
```

Comment: @alfrego129 Please mark this as the correct answer, as the other answer is filtering by specific ports on a given protocol.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is long time after but this link from  wireshark is good https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkBuildDisplayFilterSection.html

If you want to Filter in protocols you can use

http||dns||irc (The `||` is an or)

If you want to Filter out protocols you can use

!http&&!dns&&!irc (The `&&` is an and)

Answer (score 0):

Use "or" to combine multiple possible matches as a filter.

E.g.

```
tcp.port eq 80 or tcp.port eq 53 or tcp.port eq 194
```

Comment: Hi, I do not need ports I just wanna see general protocols and combine them, so I just one see all HTTP, IRC and DNS traffic on Wireshark and would like eliminate all the other traffic, how can I do it?

Comment: @alfrego129 Yes that's what this filter does. It will only match the three protocols you asked for. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes I have tried and seen just eliminated TCP protocol traffic but my pcap includes HTTP, IRC and so on...

Comment: So you do NOT want to see those protocols? Then invert the statement. Use "ne" instead of "eq" and "and" instead of "or". You should really learn to formulate the question properly so people don't have to guess what you are meaning.

Comment: When I filter HTTP I see just HTTP traffic when I filter IRC I just see IRC traffic, so I just wanna combine both of them and DNS and wanna see 3 of them, when I try your command I see TCP traffic as well. Just wanna filter HTTP, IRC and DNS, do not wanna see the other traffic.

Comment: Sorry, filter means I just want to see these 3 protocols, not want to see the other protocols like TCP and so on.